# App Engine IN_USE_ADDRESSES quotas for External IP?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am hitting this quota and I was wondering wether this quota for `External IP`?

`INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES (quota: 8, used: 7 + needed: 2).`

I have a few services that work via pub/sub and making request outside. Do I still need `External IP`? Or somehow I can set and use `Internal IP`?

Meantime I made a request to increase but want to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quota is related to the [ephemeral IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#ip_addresses) used by App Engine. Actually App Engine will always use External IPs, you cannot avoid that, you may want to take a look on how App Engine manages IPs in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip).

Everytime you deploy a new version of your app, App Engine by default will retain the old versions with its IPs. You can avoid this situation by stopping the previous versions on [deployment](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) with the flag `--stop-previous-version`.

This is also already answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/869418/google-cloud-in-use-addresses-quota-exceeded).

Comment: let me give a try. Thanks for response!